# unity how to avoid scaling heritage when parenting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I write this code, my object scaling some numbers. I don't want to scale the object. But I want to my object stay above the platform but not scale.

```
if (collision.tag=="MovingPlatform")
    {
        ShootScript.ShootCount +=1;
        myBody.drag = 10f;
        gameObject.transform.parent = collision.transform;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of setting the transform, only set the position coordinates. It'll take more lines of code but you will assign less things unintentionally. I have a feeling the scale is coming from your transform.

Comment: But When I set position to other's it will be 1  times.So,there isn't seem smooth look.

Comment: You mentioned you want to stay above the platform. You could set the position.Z component to your platform.Z + platform.Height

Comment: This may not be the answer you look for but if the children are scaling with the parent, you can to `child.transform.localScale = 1 / parent.transform.localScale`, that is, the inverse of the parent's scale.

Answer (score 2):

`transform.SetParent (collision.transform, true);`

Second parameter is **optional** and determines if global position, rotation and scaling should stay.

[Documentaion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)